# javascript variable for html tag id

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following as the code but i when i debug it from the chrome. I have seen that the id names are all +someInput +demo things like that. My aim is to pass the javascript variables to the ids. How can i do that? Thanks in advance.

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
var demo5 = "demo5"+i;
var someInput ="someInput" +i;
var demo = "demo"+i;
var demo1 = "demo1"+i;
var demo2 = "demo2"+i;
var demo3 = "demo3"+i;
var demo4 = "demo4"+i;

 document.write('<tr>');
 document.write('<td><p id=""+demo5 ></p></td>');
document.write('<td><p id=""+someInput onclick="myFunction(),myFunction5()"></p>     </td>');
document.write('<td><p id=""+demo onclick="myFunction1(),myFunction5()"></p></td>');
 document.write('<td><p id=""+demo1 onclick="myFunction2(),myFunction5()"></p></td>');
 document.write('<td><p id=""+demo2 onclick="myFunction3(),myFunction5()"></p></td>');
 document.write('<td><p id=""+demo3 onclick="myFunction4(),myFunction5()"></p></td>');
 document.write('<td><p id=""+demo4 </p></td>');
 document.write('</tr>');}
```

Comment: [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) writes to the document everything passed in the argument, literally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to concatenate the strings like

```
document.write('<td><p id="' + demo5 + '" ></p></td>');
```

in order to get your desired result. In your post, JS will interpret `'... id=""+demo'` as a string, not escaped and not using the variable value.

EDIT: per comments added the '+'

Comment: I think you are missing `+` after demo5.

Answer (score 0):

in your example variable treat as string thats whats it's interpret same. see below i have concaternate the variable enclose with ''

```
  for(i=0;i<5;i++){
var demo5 = "demo5"+i;
var someInput ="someInput" +i;
var demo = "demo"+i;
var demo1 = "demo1"+i;
var demo2 = "demo2"+i;
var demo3 = "demo3"+i;
var demo4 = "demo4"+i;

 document.write('<tr>');
 document.write('<td><p id=""+demo5 ></p></td>');
document.write('<td><p id=""+someInput onclick="myFunction(),myFunction5()"></p>     </td>');
document.write('<td><p id="'+demo+'" onclick="myFunction1(),myFunction5()"></p></td>');
 document.write('<td><p id="'+demo1+'" onclick="myFunction2(),myFunction5()"></p></td>');
 document.write('<td><p id="'+demo2+'" onclick="myFunction3(),myFunction5()"></p></td>');
 document.write('<td><p id="'+demo3+'" onclick="myFunction4(),myFunction5()"></p></td>');
 document.write('<td><p id="'+demo4+'"> </p></td>');
 document.write('</tr>');}
```